# Determine if a Patch is Installed using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.PatchInstallation

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, dtf

I thought this would be fairly straightforward but I'm having problems using the PatchInstallation class which is part of Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.

Having obtained the correct patch code and product code (targetcode), I'm simply calling the IsInstalled property, but ArgumentNullExceptions are being thrown.

```
PatchInstallation patchInstallation = new PatchInstallation(patchCode.ToString("B"), productCode.ToString("B"));
return patchInstallation.IsInstalled;
```

Exception text is:

> System.ArgumentNullException occurred   Message=Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: String   Source=mscorlib   ParamName=String
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean
>   parseDecimal)
>          at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>          at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.PatchInstallation.get_State()
>          at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.PatchInstallation.get_IsInstalled()
>   InnerException:

If anyone has any ideas what I'm doing wrong please let me know!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose a context before you can get a patch's state. Use the four-argument constructor that takes a UserContexts and choose one of UserManaged, UserUnmanaged, or Machine.

Comment: I've already tried using the four-argument constructor passing the userSid and UserContext.  I pass null for userSid and I've tried All, UserManaged, UserUnmanaged, and Machine.  All with the same result of argument null exception when accessing the IsInstalled property.  It looks to me like the constructor is missing a param for PatchStates.

Comment: If the user context isn't UserManaged, UserUnmanaged, or Machine, DTF uses an MSI API function that doesn't support getting the patch state. However, there are any number of errors that DTF ignores and returns null instead. I'd suggest debugging through the DTF call so you can see the error code directly.